# Is 'I don't know' an adjective?

Tags: phrases, parts-of-speech

Other than being an interjection, does 'I don't know' serve as an adjective?

Comment: [Who's on first, What's on second, and I don't know's on third.](https://youtu.be/kTcRRaXV-fg)

Comment: If it's used in an I-don't-know way, it certainly functions as a modifier in a manner essentially equivalent to that of an adjective phrase.

Answer (score 2):

"I don't know" is a sentence, not an interjection and not an adjective.

I suppose you could make it one, rather artificially.

> Every contestant has a green "yes" light, a red "no" light, and an amber "I don't know" light.